# Symfony2 / Doctrine2 : how to access an entity annotation mapping?

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, annotations, mapping, accessor

In my Symfony2/doctrine2 application, I have two entities, Media and Recipe.

They can be linked by a oneToMany or a ManyToMany association.

In the case of a oneToMany relationship, I am using the following code to retrieve the Recipe linked to an instance of Media :

```
$accessor = PropertyAccess::createPropertyAccessor();
$reflect = new ReflectionClass($media);
$shortName =  $reflect->getShortName();
$value = $accessor->getValue($element, $shortName);
```

However, if the relationship is a manyToMany, and also if I gave a custom name to the property, the previous code does not work.

How can I programatically retrieve the "recipes" of the mappedBy from the annotation mapping of the Media class ?

```
/**
 * @ORM\OrderBy({"sortablePosition" = "ASC"})
 * @Assert\Valid()
 * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="\AppBundle\Entity\Core\Media", mappedBy="recipes", cascade={"persist", "remove"})
 */
protected $medias;
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you need is a class that implements `Doctrine\Common\Annotations\Reader` interface. It is registered as a `annotation_reader` service. Having this class you can get annotations of various objects using methods like `getClassAnnotation`, `getMethodAnnotations` etc. In your case a `getPropertyAnnotations` seems to be a good choice:

```
$reflClass = new \ReflectionClass($class); //$class is an instance of your entity
$refProp = $reflClass->getProperty('medias');
$annotations = $reader->getPropertyAnnotations($refProp);
```

`$annotations` is a collection of annotations. In your case there will be 3 elements. Check [doc](http://doctrine-common.readthedocs.org/en/latest/reference/annotations.html) for more info

Answer (score 2):

You can receive information about mapping from entities' metadata.

```
$metadata = $this->getDoctrine()
   ->getManager()
   ->getMetadataFactory()
   ->getMetadataFor(\Doctrine\Common\Util\ClassUtils::getClass($object))
;
```